# Setting pandas.Panel.minor_xs('attribute')

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a huge data organized by `pandas.Panel` and so I have some attributes sections as `minor_xs`.

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 7 (items) x 2527 (major_axis) x 16 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ONE 60 to ONE 66
Major_axis axis: 0 to 2526
Minor_axis axis: t068C to lon
```

I want to set the data that is shown when I call, for example, `panel.minor_xs('attribute')` from `numpy.array([])` matrix. I saw here [Pandas Website](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.minor_xs.html) that this function is jut to get, not for setting data.

> minor_xs is only for getting, not setting values.

If it be necessary, I might try to give some example data, but if doesn't, thanks a lot. Because the data is too long.

Comment: ``p.loc[:,:,indexer] = value`` is what you want (``minor_xs`` is a convience feature)

Comment: You put this as a comment, not as an answer and so I can`t vote it as the answer of the question. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
p.loc[:,:,indexer] = value
```

`minor_xs` is just a convenience accessor which is `p.loc[:,:,indexer]`